# Python nested dictionary update value where any nested key matches

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a nested dictionary where every element can be of any type including a list or 
dictionary.
I'm looking for a method to update any key at any depth with a particular value.
(So the replacement occurs if the target value is not a list or dictionary)

e.g

```
{
   'a': 1,
   'b': 2,
   'c': [{'a': 2, 'b': 3}],
   'd': [{'d_d': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}],
   'e': {'a': 4},
}
```

would become

```
{
   'a': 'xx',
   'b': 2,
   'c': [{'a': 'xx', 'b': 3}],
   'd': [{'d_d': {'a': 'xx', 'b': 2}}],
   'e': {'a': 'xx'},
}
```

where the function takes a dictionary, key and new value like so

```
update_nested(dict, key='a', value='xx')
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you add  your code and tell us at which part you are stuck

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  In particular, post your code so far and the problems you have with it; there are many references that show you how to dig through a nested structure, usually using a recursive routine.

Comment: What would be the expected result for the following dict: `{'a': {'a': 1}}`?

Comment: I guess it will be `{'a' : 'xx'}`

Comment: {'a': {'a': 1}} should yiled {'a': {'a': 'xx'}} since this is the leaf element we are updating

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at which parts you need and how to implement them:

### iterate over a dictionary

there are three different methods that help you to iterate over a dictionary:

#### [dict.keys()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys)

iterating over all keys in the dict. e.g.

```
for key in {"Hello": 10, "World", 20}.keys():
   print(k)
# output: Hello\nWorld
```

#### [dict.items()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)

iterating over all `(key, value)` tuples in the dict. `for k, v in d.items()`

#### [dict.values()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values)

iterating over all values in the dict. `for v in d.values()`

### Handle nested dictionaries

When you have nested structures a good concept would [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))

In short: You call the same function in itself with different parameters.

putting both concepts together.

- Iterate over the array
- If the key is the same as the one you are searching for: Replace the value
- If the value is a dict: Call the function again with the value as dict parameter
- If the value is a list: Iterate over all items and check if they are dicts. If so handle them like above

Possible final code:

```
def update_nested(in_dict, key, value):
   for k, v in in_dict.items():
       if key == k:
           in_dict[k] = value
       elif isinstance(v, dict):
           update_nested(v, key, value)
       elif isinstance(v, list):
           for o in v:
               if isinstance(o, dict):
                   update_nested(o, key, value)
```

#### Extra note:

You should never use a builtin name/type as a variable name. In your case `dict`. This will override the builtin type and can lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: great. small update  dict[k] = value should be  in_dict[k] = value on line 4

Comment: If the original dict is an OrderedDict (from Collections.OrderedDict, + Python 3.8) , will the update_nested change the order?  Will the dict maintain its order established under the original OrderedDict type?

Comment: This function also removes other key-value from the original json which are not listed as changes in dict.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive function that checks on instances of `dict` and `list`:

```
def nested_update(obj, key, value):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for k, v in obj.items():
            if isinstance(v, (dict, list)):
                nested_update(v, key, value)
            elif k == key:
                obj[k] = value
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for item in obj:
            nested_update(item, key, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

This function updates at any depth and remove all None values so keys can be deleted.

```py
def deep_update(main_dict, update_dict):
  main_dict.update([(k, deep_update(main_dict[k], v) if isinstance(main_dict.get(k), dict) and isinstance(v, dict) else v) for k, v in update_dict.items()])
  return dict((k, v) for k, v in main_dict.items() if v is not None)
```

Comment: If you like to keep the None values just "return main_dict"

Answer (score 1):

Based on [@Peter Korinek TellusTalk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73200717/5340217)'s answer, here's one that can deal with `dict` *and `list`* according to the question.

```py
def deep_update(main_dict: dict, update_dict: dict):
    main_dict.update([(k, deep_update(main_dict[k], v) if isinstance(main_dict.get(k), dict) and isinstance(v, dict) else [deep_update(main_dict[k][i], v[i]) for i in range(len(v))] if isinstance(main_dict.get(k), list) and isinstance(v, list) else v) for k, v in update_dict.items()])
    return dict((k, v) for k, v in main_dict.items() if v is not None)
```

The results:

```py
deep_update({"a": {"b": 1}, "b": {"b": 2}}, {"a": 3, "b": {"c": 3}})
# {'a': 3, 'b': {'b': 2, 'c': 3}}
deep_update({"a": [{"b": 1, "c": 2}]}, {"a": [{"c": 1}]})
# {'a': [{'b': 1, 'c': 1}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to update imported JSON values in varying nested dictionaries.

Using @Uli Sotschok's solution, this is my working code:

```
def changejsonimage(key, value, dictionary):
    for k,v in dictionary.items():
        if isinstance(v, str) and 'images' in v: #if string and has 'images' in the value
            dictionary[k] = 'InlineImage(tpl,"' + v + '")' #change the value
        elif isinstance(v, dict): #any value that is a dictionary, loop back into the fn
            changejsonimage(key,value,v)
```